# Unable to open apache2 web page from Deb10 linux distribution with hostname

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

Good afternoon! I'm attempting to setup virtual web server hosting with Apache2, and I'm running into a specific problem where I'm only able to search the web servers by the IP address and not the hostname. The pages are working and accessible, but only if searched with the full IP address.

I've confirmed that the host names are properly applied in /etc/hosts, I've created the configuration files, document root directories, and index.html files, I'm just unable to open them by the hostname in the browser for some reason. Even using .local when searching returns an error about server not found.

Comment: Please elaborate on what `virtual web server hosting` means to you. Also: `where` (on which machine) did you ad the name to `/etc/hosts`?  Are you running the browser on the same machine as the service?

Comment: Thank you; right now, I'm just trying to get it to work with the default apache2 page locally hosted from a virtual machine. I am using the browser within the host machine, and then the /etc/hosts information and apache2 information is on a virtual machine within Virtual Machine Manager. Typing this out I'm starting to wonder if I need to update /ect/hosts from the host machine instead of the virutal machine. I'm trying that now.

Comment: Having looked at the info provided I think you'd be best served reposting this over at [su] with more details filled in - this doesn't really look like a programming problem, but one of basic understanding of Linux  configuration & network set-up. Voting to close this question as off-topic here.

Comment: Please add enough information to identify a problem. Nobody want to pull information out your nose to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the assumption that the website loads properly by IP.  Please ensure the hostname resolves from terminal.  If so, in your web browser if it's still giving you problems, manually type the full URL: `http://lazy-hostname/index.html` for example.. you likely won't need the file, but be sure to end your hostname with the slash, so the browser knows you're done provind that part of the URI.

Some browsers like to assume you intend to do other things if you just start typing and it's only resolving from local DNS, you probably need to be pretty explicit. A good trick to avoid dealing with this, if the above works, is to be sure to make a bookmark, or any other link (can put a shortcut on your desktop if it suits you).. this'll save you from having to type the schema explicitly, etc..

I am also assuming your apache2 is pretty default and that you haven't gone and disabled the default apache modules.